# Resharper possible null reference warning

Tags: c#, casting, resharper

Resharper gives a possible null reference warning for the as cast here.  Is there any possibility of it actually happening, or does the is check in the if statement preclude it?

```
IMyObjectType someObject = null; //MyObjectType implements IMyObjectType
if (someObject is MyObjectType)
{
    (someObject as MyObjectType).SomePropery = true;
}
```

Comment: BTW, it doesn't show warning *on my machine*. Resharper ver 5.1.3. Having `someObject` as class field.

Comment: @ Snowbear JIM-compiler Weird.  I'm running 5.1.3000.12 (same as 5.1.3?).  I wonder what's different between my actual code and this example?

Comment: @Dan, yep, I also have `5.1.3000.12`. Don't know what's the reason. Your current code gives only `expression is always false` warning but even if I will ignore it I do not have any more warnings.

Comment: @Snowbear JIM-compiler  Was pebkac on my part.  I was checking someObject and then casting someObject2, both IMyObjectType.  Other constraints require someObject and someObject2 to always be the same type (MyObjectType, MyObjectType2, etc); but there's no obvious way for resharper to be able to figure that out.

Comment: At least realizing the actual problem will make it easy to shut resharper up.

Comment: @Dan, So it looks like Resharper knew it better than you :-) Don't blame resharper and be aware of Resharper, next time he will post a bug report on you in advance.

Comment: @Snowbear JIM-compiler in the ideal world the fact that my brain's apparently decided to call it quits for the weekend would mean my body could go home now too.  *sigh*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit:** Whoops I was all wrong here - here is the right answer:

The `is` operator checks for type compatibility *and* nullity so ReSharper should not warn in this particular case.

**Proof**:

```
using System;

class Example
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Example example = null;

        // this is always "false"
        Console.WriteLine(example is Example);
    }
}
```

**More proof:**

[is (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx):

> An is expression evaluates to true ***if
>   the provided expression is non-null***,
>   and the provided object can be cast to
>   the provided type without causing an
>   exception to be thrown.

---

**Old answer:** *This is incorrect but for the sake of completeness I will leave it here.*

Yes, `someObject` can still be `null` here.

This only checks the type of the *variable*:

```
someObject is MyObjectType
```

The type of `someObject` could very well be `MyObjectType` but could point nowhere.  In other words, there is a difference between the *type* of the reference and whether or not that reference points to an instance of an object.

Comment: How can it still be null? I can't find a way in testing that I can get someObject to be null and pass the IF.

Comment: Ok, that's true.  I was thrown by it's suggested fix of changing the lineto `((MyObjectType) someObject).SomePropery = true;`, but if someObject is null this wouldn't help although resharper thinks it's fine if I made the change.

Comment: Not true, if someObject is null `someObject is MyObjectType will evaluate to false. http://dotnetpad.net/ViewPaste/BaF94diL6EGbrfZyhHCXOQ

Comment: `object o = null; if (o is object) throw null;` This doesn't throw because `null` seems to always return `null` on `is`.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, the `is` check precludes it.**

<strike>As it turns out, your is check doesn't protect you from all cases. Consider the following:</strike>

```
MyObjectType obj = null;
ParentType someObject = obj;
```

In this case, the `is` check will succeed but the value will still be `null`.

**Update**

I was curious when I wrote the example above if I was correct or not. It turns out that I was not. The is check above will always return false (because the actual value is null).

You could make this a little cleaner and remove the warning by changing your code to:

```
var castObject = someObject as MyObjectType;

if(castObject != null)
    castObject.SomeProperty = true;
```

Comment: hmmm, just tested this myself, and it looks like that's only true if someObject is MyObjectType.  In this case it's IMyObject, and while MyObjectType implements IMyObject, if I set it to null it doesn't pass into the if statement.

Comment: It's the thing with the null pointer, hence the `NullReferenceException`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think ReSharper will be that smart. But in any event what I commonly see is something along the lines of

```
MyObjectType someTypedObject = someObject as MyObjectType;
if (someTypedObject != null)
{
// use the object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also a bit curious about this, but I can see that you pretty much already have answered the question.

However, since I made this nice image for you, I might as well upload it:
[image]